# Netsuite webservices upload and get url in C#

Tags: file, url, netsuite

When I upload file I get **internalId** as response.
My requirement is to get **fileURL**.

Eg: to get internalId `((RecordRef)(writeRes.baseRef)).internalId))`
Is there any way to get **fileURL** after uploading?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a new request to get the file once it's uploaded:

```
var internalId = ((RecordRef)(writeRes.baseRef)).internalId));

RecordRef file = new RecordRef();
recordRef.internalId = internalId;
recordRef.type = RecordType.file;
recordRef.typeSpecified = true;

ReadResponse response = service.get(recordRef);

File file = (File)(response.record); 

var fileUrl = file.url;
```

Comment: I tried long solution, like getting all files and than looping each to get particular url. your approach is simplest! Thaks Andres!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @SampatPatil If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)